# TinyMCE with ReactJs - onChange event only firing once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

I'm using tinyMCE with my reactjs app. The onChange event will fire once, properly reflecting the input data in an alert. Then I get nothing.

Here's the relevant code:

```
<Editor init={{
    statusbar: false,
    menubar: false,
    }}
    onChange={this.SetText}
 />
```

onChange method:

```
SetText(e) {
    alert(e.target.getContent());
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually the event you using is not right. For reactJs plugIn they have [onEditorChange](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/#tinymcereactintegrationquickstartguide). You can use it as following

```
<Editor
  apiKey="MyAPIKey"
  initialValue=""
  init={{
    height: 500,
    menubar: false,
    plugins: [
      'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
      'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
      'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
    ],
    toolbar:
      'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | \
      alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
      bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help'
  }}
  onEditorChange={this.onChange}
/>
```

and then you can access editor's content by using

```
  onChange = (content) => {
    console.log(content);
  }
```

`e.target` is not required

Comment: I ended up going with a different editor, but I just now realized you gave the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of this events pass better then onChange?

- KeyDown   - Fires when a key is pressed within the editor.
- KeyPress - Fires when a key is pressed within the editor.
- KeyUp - Fires when a key is released within the editor.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/events/

Comment: Well, I think I should stick to the native reactjs events when modifying state, should I not? Either way I may play with them because I'm at a loss right now.

Comment: I think, what you can modify state with tinyMCE events. But yout should bind your function in constructor (or use array function) to get component context in event method.

Comment: Yeah. Well, I'll give it a try in a bit. If it turns out to be viable and nobody can answer why onChange is firing only once, I'll check you off for the solution. Thanks